# Is GalaSoft.MvvmLight compatible with .NET 3.5?

Tags: mvvm-light

Is there an existing version of GalaSoft.MvvmLight that targets .NET 3.5? If no, what is the easiest way to make MvvmLight target .NET 3.5? I want to use GalaSoft.MvvmLight in a legacy .NET 3.5 project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are, this one for example supports WPF 3.5 https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/96993

This old one also does https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/34592